# Why would a step function cancels itself when there are no errors

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a step function (illustrated below) and I was working out the few remaining issues when all of a sudden I hit a rather unexpected result:

- All tasks that have completed, completed successfully without error
- All remaining tasks simulateously cancel themselves (also no error)

[image]

I'm a bit dumbfounded. Has anyone seen this? Does anyone know how I'd go about troubleshooting it?

Comment: Take a look at execution history (list of events at the bottom of a page with execution). Especially check what happend at the end. It's possible that your execution has reached timeout or maximum number of state transitions.

Comment: i faced the same problem and dumbfounded for a while. Check the execution event history, to the step where the task failed. i found out that my task failed to due to improper mentioning of a json key. I was able to resolve it!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This may not match your case, but this happens in step functions when you have a `Choice` state, and the `Variable` you are referencing is not actually in the state input.

The documentation says:

> **Note**:
>
> You must specify the $.type field. If the state input doesn't contain
>   the $.type field, the execution fails and an error is displayed in the
>   execution history.

but from my experience, you get a `Cancelled` state.

Have a look here for more info: [AWS Step Functions - Choice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html)

Comment: I have been off on other adventures recently but I'll have a look at this once I'm back on this project. Sounds highly plausible.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason could be that it reaches a quota limit, like for instance if your state machine reaches 25K events in the event history it will get canceled.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I tried to start an AWS Batch Job in my step functions using the `arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync` resource type but provided not all parameters as Strings. But the additional `Parameters` [has to be a String to String map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_SubmitJob.html#Batch-SubmitJob-request-parameters).

So in my case the failing payload was

```
{
  "FieldName": 2
}
```

but has to be

```
{
  "FieldName": "2"
}
```